# Conventions for Tcl proc return

Tags: tcl

What are conventions for Tcl proc return values? A proc can return a value in the normal termination case, that's fine. But what about exceptions? What's a good value to return if the proc returns no programmatic value? Is it '0', '-1', '/dev/null', 'True', 'False'?

Comment: You may take a look at https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/return.htm#M5 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what about exceptions?

If you've got an error, use `error` to indicate it. It creates an exception condition that bubbles outwards and that can be trapped with `catch`. In Tcl 8.6, you can also use `throw` and `try`/`trap` to do this.

In some cases, it's clearer to do `return -code error` as that makes the procedure produce the error, not the particular location in it where you detected the issue.

> What's a good value to return if the proc returns no programmatic value?

The usual “no value” value is the empty string. If you just do `return`, that's what the value actually is. Many Tcl commands that you know (e.g., `puts`, `for`) will produce the empty string as their result. If you're using Tcl interactively, the Tcl interpreter loop doesn't print anything for empty results.

Answer (score 1):

As with many things Tcl, convention is varied, pragmatic, and permissive. You are encouraged to use exceptions (through `error`, `throw`, or `return`, mainly, also `continue` and `break` for iteration control, etc) rather than return special values that indicate that something has gone wrong.

Even so, return values such as

- values outside of the command's result range (such as -1 when the range is integers ≥0)
- the empty string
- boolean falsity (`false`, `off`, `no`, or zero)

are often used when a command can't return a useful value. Commands that *never* return useful values because only their side-effects are considered useful (such as `unset`) almost always return the empty string.

(Note that commands returning strings have no out-of-range value, since all possible values are valid strings.)

Sometimes it just makes more sense to use special return values; other times raising errors is more convenient, if maybe somewhat confusing for inexperienced users. Dictionary access with a non-existent key is an example. If Tcl had a `null` value, `dict get $foo not-a-key` would probably return that; instead you get an exception.

Documentation: [break](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/break.htm), [continue](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/continue.htm), [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm), [error](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/error.htm), [return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm), [throw](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/throw.htm), [unset](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/unset.htm)